# Catch Specific MySQL-Error (C#)

Tags: c#, mysql, database, exception, visual-studio-2012

Is there way to catch a specific MySQL Error or more than one specific MySQL-Error?
I want to call a method if the error is "no selected database".

I am working with the MySQL-Connector / Net.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `catch` clause of your exception, you should be able to examine the [`Number`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-ref-mysqlclient-mysqlexceptionmembers.html) property of the exception to determine which MySql exception was thrown. For example:

```
try
{
    //Blah
}
catch (MySqlException ex)
{
    if (ex.Number == 1046)
    {
        //Handle
    }
    throw;
}
catch (OtherExceptionType oet)
{
    //Handle
}
```

If you are using C# 6.0, you can use exception filters.

```
try
{
    //Blah
}
catch (MySqlException ex) when (ex.Number == 1046)
{
    // Handle
}
catch (OtherExceptionType oet)
{
    //Handle
}
```

The error number for "no database selected" is 1046 according to [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/error-messages-server.html). Other error numbers are listed there as well.

Comment: ex.Number = 416 // No database selected

Comment: The number is [1046](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/error-messages-server.html)

Comment: It's a MySqlException.